# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found while using 64bit Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using a base64 encoding for my parameter, it was working on local server but when I published it, it redirects me.

Here is the encrypted URL : http://192.168.1.8/Admin/TeacherInformation?q=3c0WJjr9NfgF2rRzR3DDtAk8hAaDvGXS

And this is the error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I tried several solutions but none of them work.

Here is how I am passing my parameter using `EncodedActionLink`:

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink("View Account", "TeacherInformation", "Admin", new { TeacherNumber = tchr.TeacherNumber }, null)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MVCInvoicClient.Extensions
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString EncodedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            string htmlAttributesString = string.Empty;
            if (routeValues != null)
            {
                RouteValueDictionary d = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
                for (int i = 0; i < d.Keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        queryString += "?";
                    }
                    queryString += d.Keys.ElementAt(i) + "=" + d.Values.ElementAt(i);
                }
            }

            if (htmlAttributes != null)
            {
                RouteValueDictionary d = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
                for (int i = 0; i < d.Keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    htmlAttributesString += " " + d.Keys.ElementAt(i) + "=" + d.Values.ElementAt(i);
                }
            }

            //<a href="/Answer?questionId=14">What is Entity Framework??</a>
            StringBuilder ancor = new StringBuilder();
            ancor.Append("<a ");
            if (htmlAttributesString != string.Empty)
            {
                ancor.Append(htmlAttributesString);
            }
            ancor.Append(" href='");
            if (controllerName != string.Empty)
            {
                ancor.Append("/" + controllerName);
            }

            if (actionName != "Index")
            {
                ancor.Append("/" + actionName);
            }
            if (queryString != string.Empty)
            {
                ancor.Append("?q=" + Encrypt(queryString));
            }
            ancor.Append("'");
            ancor.Append(">");
            ancor.Append(linkText);
            ancor.Append("</a>");
            return new MvcHtmlString(ancor.ToString());
        }

        private static string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            string key = "jdsg432387#";
            byte[] EncryptKey = { };
            byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
            EncryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] inputByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, des.CreateEncryptor(EncryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cStream.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);
            cStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCInvoicClient.Extensions
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class EncryptedActionParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            Dictionary<string, object> decryptedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("q") != null)
            {
                string encryptedQueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("q");
                string decrptedString = Decrypt(encryptedQueryString.ToString());
                string[] paramsArrs = decrptedString.Split('?');

                for (int i = 0; i < paramsArrs.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] paramArr = paramsArrs[i].Split('=');
                    decryptedParameters.Add(paramArr[0], Convert.ToString(paramArr[1]));
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < decryptedParameters.Count; i++)
            {
                filterContext.ActionParameters[decryptedParameters.Keys.ElementAt(i)] = decryptedParameters.Values.ElementAt(i);
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        }

        private string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {

            string key = "jdsg432387#";
            byte[] DecryptKey = { };
            byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
            byte[] inputByte = new byte[encryptedText.Length];

            DecryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            encryptedText = encryptedText.Replace(' ', '-');
            inputByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(DecryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);

            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please not that Base64 is an encoding and NOT an encryption!
Otherwise I cannot help you. You could add the code for your controller that is mapped to the given url.

Comment: i added the source code for the encoding.

Comment: As far as I know, the 404 error means the page not found. I suggest you could firstly use cmd ping the http://192.168.1.8/ to make sure you could access the server. Then I suggest you could check the url http://192.168.1.8/ could access your MVC application other pages. I guess there are something wrong with your IIS or network setting.